Expectation of covariate conditional on regression, $E[X\mid Y=f(X,Z)]$
Suppose $X $ is a covariate in a regression model so $Y = f(X, Z) $ where $f$ is some (non-linear) link function and $Z$ is some other covariate. What is the $E[X\mid Y]$?
Would $E[X\mid Y] = E[X\mid X] = X$? I don't think that would make sense, because say $Y$ is some event indicator. You might expect age to be higher among those with event vs not, for example.  But at the same time, $Y$ contains $X$, so I'm unsure.

If you were trying to estimate $X$ from $Y$, I would have thought your regression model would be the other way round.

I'm doing some wacky conditional average treatment effect estimation where treatment is randomized. Imagine outcome O = T + X + Y + TX + TY where Y = f(X, Y). Then E[O|T=1, Y] - E[O|T=0, Y] = 1 + E[X|Y] + Y but in my problem, Y = f(X, Z). Just curious if there is easy/intuitive way to parse this.

How can $Y=f(X, Y) $? You can start looking at $\mathbf E[X\mid X+Z]$ to see what happens.

Y=f(X, Z) not f(X,Y). Y is like a "cluster." For example, maybe Y = 1 if in good health or 0 if in bad health. But good health and bad health dictated by some aggregation of patient characteristics, like age (X) and weight (Z) for example. Hopefully this makes sense?

Looking at E[X|X+Z] is a good starting point. I guess it would really depend on the joint distribution of X and Z, and then here the link function would introduce some weirdness... Hm, I'm guessing no nice simple answer. Boo!
